# Assigning Items to Containers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of containers

| containerID | capacity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |

And a table of items

| itemID | containerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 |  |
| 10 |  |
| 11 |  |
| 12 |  |

And I want this. The first container holds 2, so the first 2 records go in container 1, the next 5 in container 2, the next container holds 10 but there are 5 left so the rest go in the last container.

| itemID | containerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |

I have simplified this to ask this question, but you can assume that the containers available will hold all the items available.

I can usually find a solution on here, but I didn't know how to word my search to find something.

I thought I could assign a sequence to the item table like

```
select 
(Row_number()
           OVER(
             ORDER BY itemid) - 1 ) / 2 + 1 AS seq
```

then use that to match up with my containers, but that isn't dynamic as the capacity of containers isn't static.

Comment: *I want* is not actually a question - what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show your current attempt please

Comment: You write "I have simplified this to ask this question...". Are you sure this is correct? I'm always skeptical when people write such things. Often, it is better to explain the real situation and real issue.

Comment: Also is it sql - MySQL or SQL Server or Postgres etc...

Comment: sql-server, I simplified the question to avoid how I get to these tables, but these tables are the real situation and the real issue. It is very simple problem but I am not sure the best way to attempt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a cte returning the running sum of container capacity. `JOIN` with Items table. Do a `GROUP BY` and use `MIN()` to find the "first" container having the capacity for the item.

```
with runningcap as (select containerID, sum(capacity) over (order by containerID) cap
                    from containers)
select i.itemid, min(rc.containerID)
from items i
join runningcap rc
  on rc.cap >= i.itemid
group by i.itemid
order by i.itemid
```

Demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/vDZwPPdI

Comment: I ended up just putting the "cap" field directly in the containers table and updated it using the code you used for the cte, but this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While I really think that @jarlh's answer is better, this is also an approach that would work:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.containerId, c.capacity, 
       n.num 
  FROM containers c
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) num 
    FROM  sys.all_objects) n 
  ON c.capacity >= n.num
)

SELECT i.itemid, n.containerId
FROM items i
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT containerId , Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY containerId) num  
  FROM cte) n 
ON i.itemid = n.num
```

Fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/DAar-uhW

Comment: You could also use items table instead of sys.all_objects in the cte.https://dbfiddle.uk/rJ_C-ccv